# Class in Kotlin with optional members

Tags: json, class, kotlin

I want to design a class in Kotlin with multiple members. At any point of time any object of this class will have only a few populated members, with the rest of them all being null. I would also like to convert this into a json, where the null members will not be there at all. I want to construct this object such that I don't have to pass null for each and every member that I populate. For example:

```
class Foo{
    var a,
    var b,
    var c,
    var d..
    .
    .
    //and so on
}
```

I want to construct this object as

```
Foo(a="a", c="c", x="x")
```

All the rest of the members should be null.

When I construct JSON for this it should look like:

```
{
    "a"="a",
    "c"="c",
    "x"="x"
}
```

Also, I will be creating this object from Java. Is there some workaround that could help me achieve this?

Comment: Question: is the number of members fixed?

Comment: @Pietro, No. It may change in the future.

Comment: So i think you'd better use a Key-Value map. Is easy to serialize and also easy to deserialize

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin supports default initialization. Note that this requires constructors, and with that many vars you should use a primary constructor. Since you want null, it needs to be a nullable type, so:

```
class Foo(
    var a: String? = null,
    var b: String? = null,
    var c: String? = null,
    var d: String? = null
    // and so on
)
```

With default values, you can now pick what you pass. Note that this only applies to Kotlin; you have to pass all if you  create the object from Java. The same applies with named arguments, which is why this would only work from Kotlin. Since you don't have named arguments, you'd be forced to pass arguments for all the unfilled variables.

Comment: I will need to create the object from Java

Comment: You can't. Java does [support the default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348084/kotlin-function-default-arguments-from-java) with an annotation, but it doesn't support named arguments. You said you had some json; if you use a library like Jackson, it likely uses reflection to load the values into the class. I'm not sure how it handles null arguments, but you can't do named arguments from Java, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
data class Foo(var a: String? = null,
           var b: String? = null)
```

And creating:

```
Foo(b = "")
```